# Legacy C# to PHP

Tags: c#, php, tcp

I have recently taken over a legacy service and I'm in the process of converting it to PHP, however I have gotten stuck with the more intricate functionality of C#.

From what I see the request message length needs to be packed and then concatted with the actual message before being sent to the service.

```
string strReceiveBuffer;
string msg1 = string.Empty;
msg1 = msg1 + txtRqst.Text;
Int64 intMessageLength = msg1.Length;
byte byt1; byte byt2;

//The below should work assuming a 16 bit register.
byt1 = Convert.ToByte(decimal.Truncate(intMessageLength/ 256));
byt2 = Convert.ToByte(decimal.Remainder(intMessageLength, 256));
string strLength = string.Empty;
strLength = strLength 
    + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Chr(byt1).ToString() 
    + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Chr(byt2).ToString();

//Only encode the length using BigEndianCode, the message content is encoded using UTF8
byte[] byteData = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(strLength)
    .Concat(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg1)).ToArray();
```

Is anybody able to help with the above code before I tear my hair out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anybody that has to convert C# to PHP, good luck. After struggling with variations of encoding and decoding I finally managed to translate it to PHP.

```
function convertRequest($msg) {
    $length = strlen($msg);
    $byt1 = intval($length / 256);
    $byt2 = $length % 256;
    $strLength = mb_convert_encoding((string) chr($byt1) . (string) chr($byt2), 'UTF-16BE');
    $msg = mb_convert_encoding($msg, 'UTF-8');
    $data = $strLength . $msg;
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: It's not necessarily converting C# to PHP that's the problem, it's converting horribly written code in ANY language that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick if I'm interpreting the code you posted correctly (as a side note, my gawd that's some awful code).

```
function encodeMessage($msg) {
    $data = ""; 
    $length = strlen($msg);

    $data .= pack('n', floor($length / 256)) . pack('n', $length % 256);
    $data .= $msg;

    return $data;
}
```

EDIT: I don't understand the reasoning behind the original code. For some reason it's turning the length into two separate bytes (factor and modulus of 256), then concatenating these bytes into a string, before finally using Unicode to encode the length into a 4 byte array. Because of the `Convert.ToByte` you physically can't encode a string with `length > (2^16 - 1)` (which can be held in 2 bytes), yet 4 bytes end up being used to encode the length anyway, weird.

Comment: This is from the official documentation:

<LEN1><LEN2><LEN3><LEN4><MESSAGE>

<LEN1> & <LEN2> & <LEN3> & <LEN4> Denotes the length of message string (4 bytes)